# Wrong redirection / displayed message when I make a new edit to a tag wiki

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, tag-wiki

I have just suggested a tag wiki. After the page loads I see that I made a typo, so I hit <kbd>Edit Tag Wiki</kbd> again to fix my minor typo.

When I finally hit <kbd>Save Edits</kbd>, I'm redirected to a page without any layout saying:

[image]

But this kind of message should be displayed as a red dialog and block the form submission, right?

I've looked to see if any javascript errors appear, but I see nothing strange. I'm just redirected to this *almost* blank error page.

I haven't tested other case to generate this kind of message, such as posted one comment, then an other one immediately after, etc ...

To reproduce:

- submit a tag-wiki edit
- edit it immediately
- re-submit

Comment: Looks like they just didn't ajaxified everything. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed now: you now get a little red error popup underneath the submit button:

> [image]